# Return count based on "jsonpath output options"

Tags: json, jsonpath

Apologies for the confusing title, hopefully I can explain it more concretely below.

In short, in a pipeline template, I want to have a variable with the value determined by the "amount" a jsonpath outputs.

E.g. with a command similar to this (+ some modification):

```
rolloutMaxStep=$(kubectl get rollout ${{ parameters.applicationName }} -n ${{ parameters.k8sNameSpace }} -o=jsonpath='{.strategy.canary.steps.lenght()}')
```

... with the path leading here:

```
"strategy": {
        "canary": {
            "steps": [
                {
                    "setWeight": 10
                },
                {
                    "analysis": {
                        "templates": [
                            {
                                "templateName": "responsetest"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "pause": {}
                },
                {
                    "setWeight": 30
                },
                {
                    "pause": {}
                },
                {
                    "setWeight": 60
                },
                {
                    "pause": {}
                },
                {
                    "setWeight": 80
                },
                {
                    "pause": {}
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

... I would like it to return the number "9" which will be assigned to the variable.

Tried reading up through googling but no luck thus far. Thanks in advance for reading and possibly contributing to a solution!

Comment: You have to replace  a pic with code if you need some help

Comment: Done, updated with edit.

Answer (score 0):

Found that this command worked:

```
rolloutMaxStep=$(kubectl get rollout ${{ parameters.applicationName }} -n ${{ parameters.k8sNameSpace }} -o=jsonpath='{.spec.strategy.canary.steps}' <<< "$rolloutMaxStep" >> maxStep.json
  jq length maxStep.json)
```